# how do you initialize a variable that is declared?

Tags: java

```
if (eyeColor == green)
{
    System.out.println ("If your eyes are green I recommend buying .... ");
    ....
}
```

error says

> variable green might not have been initialized

I can't display my whole code since it is for school, but I am just wondering how can I initialized it if the eyeColor from the user input (using scanner) is green?

Comment: You mean `"green"` instead of `green`? Are you trying to compare Strings?

Comment: As an aside, if eyeColor is a String, don't use `==` to compare it to another String since that compares if one object reference refers to **the exact same object as another**, which is not what you want. Use `.equals(...)` or `.equalsIgnoreCase(...)` since that tests if both Strings contain the same chars in the same order.

Comment: "I can't display my whole code since it is for school" no one asks you to do so, but we will need to see some [full but minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we could use to actually reproduce your problem. Otherwise we can only guess what is wrong with your code (beside obvious problem which is described in your error massage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your variable `eyeColor` is the input from the user. You could use the following

```
if("green".equals(eyeColor))
```

Since green is a string, and it will never change (it is always green), you can just use the string. It is also worth noting that in Java, you need to use .equals() when comparing string values, not '=='.

I would also suggest using .toLowerCase(), so that the comparison is no longer case sensitive. An example check is shown in the code below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    String eyeColor = "Green";
    if("green".equals(eyeColor.toLowerCase())){
        System.out.println ("If your eyes are green I recommend buying .... ");
    }

}
```

Comment: `if("green".equals(eyeColor.toLowerCase()))` why not just `if("green".equalsIgnoreCase(eyeColor)))`? Anyway how does your answer solve `variable green might not have been initialized` problem?

Comment: Both code snippets do essentially the same thing, so it comes down to coding style. My answer solves his problem because this person is trying to compare a users input to a string incorrectly, and I have showed a correct way to do so.

Comment: And where in question it is said that `eyeColor` and `green` are Strings? People left comment about possible problem with `==` and Strings because this is only possibility of *future* problems, not answer to *current* OP question. Your answer currently lacks any information about how to solve not initialized variable error. I see you suggested Joda style `"string".equals(variable)` instead of `variable.equals("string")` which could prevent NullPointerException if `variable` would be `null`, but this is not the same problem as described in question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the type of `green` but this is how you declare method local variables:

```
Object green = null;
```

or

```
Object green = SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE_BETTER_THAN_NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise eyeColor before you compare it. 
If it is a string, simply initialise it as an empty string:

```
String eyeColor;
eyeColor = "";
```

Before you perform any checks to see what eyeColor has been specified, you may also want to check to make sure that is is NOT still ""..